# Query list based on input list value

Tags: java, jquery

I stored data  in mongoDB  in User Collection in below format

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("571ded1a1b8bd2c34aaf3c4a"),
    "_class" : "com.unisys.workbench.domain.User",
    "userName" : "admin",
    "password" : "admin",
    "email" : "xyzq@gmail.com",
    "contact1" : "9889482416",
    "contact2" : "1234567890",
    "roles" : [ 
        {
            "roleName" : "ROLE_ADMIN"
        }
    ]
}
```

To Restive data based on roleName I written Below Query

```
List<User> users= mongoTemplate.find(new Query().addCriteria(Criteria.where("roles.$roleName").is(role)),
                    User.class);
```

But its always returning null .

For email below Query is working fine

```
mongoTemplate.findOne(new Query().addCriteria(Criteria.where("email").is(email)),
                    User.class);
```

Comment: Please format your code as code, by pressing the `{}` button in the in line editor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is the $ for?
It should be:

```
List<User> users= mongoTemplate.find(new Query().addCriteria(Criteria.where("roles.roleName").is(role)),
                User.class);
```

Comment: $ I used for Sub element .